# How add 30 days to a date in r?

Tags: r, date

I have data of dates chosen from csv excel file and it has the format of day/month/year

```
DateAchat=DataAch[which((nchar(as.character(DataAch$FrontOfficeUser_ld))==5)),"CreationDate"]

    head(DateAchat)
    [1] 07/03/2015 07/03/2015 07/03/2015 07/03/2015 07/03/2015 08/03/2015
```

Then, I want to add 30 days to the first date for example. I get no correct result

```
as.Date(DateAchat[1])+30
[1] "0007-04-19"
```

I didn't understand why I get like this??

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. (such as a `dput()` for example) so we can see what the class of the variables you are working is since that makes a big difference.

Comment: Because you use the default date format of Year/Month/Day, and 30 days after March 20, 0007 is April 19, 0007.

Comment: the class of my data is a facor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your character column into Date column with the correct 
   format.

```
    as.Date("07/03/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y") + 30
    [1] "2015-04-06"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateAchat<-as.Date(DateAchat, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
DateAchat[1]+30
```

I suppose that the variable `DateAchat` are strings in each date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do more than days with the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date("07/03/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y") + duration(30, 'days')
as.Date("07/03/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y") + duration(30, 'hours')
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing because sometimes we have dates, sometimes posixct, sometimes we need to use +days(30) , sometimes +ddays(30)